# Get google sheet cell value based on value of other cell

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

Is it possible in Google Sheets to write a formula that calculates the cell to fetch based on the value of another.

In this case I would want cell B2 to print the value of e2 so be something like:

```
='a2'2
```

Is this possible in Google Sheets?

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well. You can even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) the answer. If you don't have enough reputation, your upvote will show up later, once you reach [enough reputation points](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula in Cell B1:

`=indirect(A1&1)`

The formula consists of two parts:

- `A1&1`: this creates a string value of the cell address (E1) to be referenced.
- `indirect()`: Returns a cell reference specified by a string.

[image: snapshot]

Comment: Ah ok so the & character there is a concatenation operator?